# Why type constructors can not be used in typeclass definition in haskell?

Tags: haskell, constructor, typeclass, monoids

```
data LinkedList a = Empty | Cons a (LinkedList a)   deriving (Eq, Show)

instance  Foldable LinkedList where
  foldMap _ Empty  = mempty
  foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  LinkedList (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
```

It seems LinkedList constructor is not in scope? Why?

compiler error:

```
        Data constructor not in scope: LinkedList :: m -> m -> m
   |        
17 |   foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  LinkedList (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I  searched for a solution and it seems that I should  have used 'mappened' instead of constructor. Which is  very confusing. I have not defined anywhere any Monoid typeclass.

Can you explain why `mappened` and not the constructor? And where the `Monoid` functions `mappened` and `mempty` are defined?

Edit ---------------------------------------------------------------------

I made a mistake when I  had changed back from mappened. Sorry, but the correct question is this:

```
instance  Foldable LinkedList where
  foldMap _ Empty  = mempty
  foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  Cons (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
```

the compiler Error:

```
     • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        m ~ LinkedList m
    • In the second argument of ‘Cons’, namely ‘(foldMap f ll)’
      
   |        
17 |   foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  Cons (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
   |            

                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why can't I use foldMap recursively? And also where the Monoid functions are defined.

Comment: you have no `LinkedList` data constructor, just a type of the same name. Types and values (which include data constructors) live in completely different namespaces, even though both are capitalised.

Comment: You need to watch your spelling.  You can (sometimes) get away with that here; the computer you are programming will be far less obliging.

Comment: and as for why you need `mappend`, that's because the recursive call to `foldMap` returns a value in an arbitrary Monoid - so `mappend` (along with `mempty`) is the only thing you "know" you have.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sorry, I correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error message should contain enough detail for you to figure out what is wrong with your code:

```
     • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        m ~ LinkedList m
    • In the second argument of ‘Cons’, namely ‘(foldMap f ll)’
      
   |        
17 |   foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  Cons (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
   |            

                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Ignoring the parts about "occurs check" and "infinite type", which I accept may seem a little confusing, it's complaining that `foldMap f ll` is supposed to have type `m` when it has actual type `LinkedList m`, or possibly (as it turns out) the other way round. So let's look at the types ourselves.

It starts with the type of `foldMap`, which we can easily find in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldMap):

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

this means that `foldMap f ll` will have type `m`, for any Monoid `m` (whichever specific Monoid the caller picked as the return type of the function `f`).

Meanwhile, `f` has type `a -> m`, so `f a` must have type `m` - again for the arbitrary `Monoid` instance picked by `f`. So when `f a` is used as the first argument of `Cons` - `Cons (f a) (foldMap f ll)` - we can compare to the definition of `Cons`, which comes from the type definition:

```
data LinkedList a = Empty | Cons a (LinkedList a)
```

which tells us that, since `f a` has type `m`, `Cons (f a) (foldMap f ll)` must be supposed to be a value of type `LinkedList m`. And therefore `foldMap f ll` must have that same type. (As both of the `LinkedList` types in the definition are applied to the same type `a`.)

And this gives us the problem reported by the compiler - `foldMap f ll` must be both of type `m` and of type `LinkedList m`.

(Aside: GHC doesn't in fact give up at that point, it assumes the types actually are equal to each other and sees where that leads. But here it simply leads to an infinite regress: the value concerned must have type `m` which equals `LinkedList m` which equals `LinkedList (LinkedList m)` and so on. Haskell is fine with infinite regress like this in value definitions but doesn't allow it for types - hence "cannot construct the infinite type".)

How do we fix this error and get a correct `foldMap` definition? You had absolutely the right idea in trying to combine `f a` and `foldMap f ll` in computing `foldMap f (Cons a ll)`. Both of those are of type `m`, for the particular (arbitrary) Monoid targeted by the `f`. We can't necessarily combine those with a "normal function" like, say, `(+)`, because we don't know what type `m` is - it won't necessarily be a numeric type, or whatever. But the one thing we do know is that it is an instance of [Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monoid) - and therefore that we can indeed combine any two such values with the `Monoid` method `mappend`. And in fact, we can't really do much else, because we know *nothing* about the type `m` here *except* that it's an instance of `Monoid` - and therefore has `mappend :: m -> m -> m` (and `mempty :: m`) available.

So there's only one way to combine these values into the correct definition, which is:

```
foldMap f (Cons a ll) = mappend (f a) (foldMap f ll)
```

There is no `Cons` (or `Empty`) to be seen on the right - if this puzzles you, consider that `foldMap` takes a `LinkedList` as *input* (in this particular case that's the `Cons a ll` argument), but it doesn't output a `LinkedList`, it instead outputs a value in the arbitrarily-chosen Monoid `m`.

I hope this helps, but it may be a little hard to follow if you've not come across `Monoid`s much before - especially if you're trying to understand `Foldable` without first understanding Monoids. I would highly recommend reading further around these topics, including the excellent [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) as a starting point (in this context, mostly the sections on Monoid and Foldable).

Comment: Thank you very much. very complete and insightful.

Answer (score 4):

In

```hs
data LinkedList a = Empty | Cons a (LinkedList a)
```

you have

- `LinkedList`, which is a *type* constructor: it takes as argument the general *type* `a` and gives you back the type `LinkedList a`;
- `Cons`, which is a *value* constructor: it takes as argument a *value* of general type `a` and a *value* of type `LinkedList a`.

On the other hand, here

```hs
  foldMap f (a `Cons` ll) =  LinkedList (f a)  (foldMap f ll)
```

you're using `LinkedList` as if was a *value* constructor, which is erroneous.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. when going back from mappend.